# Affine Functions, Möbius and Hyperbolic

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I haven't been able to figure out the relationship between objects in an [Exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27413/excercise-in-isometries-of-the-half-upper-plane?rq=1) of Do Carmo's book on Riemannian Geometry and this may be a bit vague, but I am posting out of despair.

I want to understand how the hyperbolic metric arises on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$, but struggle to understand why Do Carmo starts with $g(t) = yt +x$.

The following steps aim to make my question more precise, but not well defined:

1. The functions $f(t) = yt +x$ ($x,y \in \mathbb{R}, y>0$) define a group under composition, which can be understood as the upper half plane.
2. Under composition, these functions define a group. We use this to define a left invariant metric, that at $e = (0,1)$ coincides with the usual scalar product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($\langle u,v \rangle_{(f_2t+f_1)} = f_2^{-2}\langle u, v \rangle_e$).
3. So far, we have $(G,\circ)$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ and our defined metric.
4. Now, in part (b) of the Exercise, we add the complex upper half plane (which I write $\mathbb{H}$). It inherits complex multiplication and addition. We are asked to prove that $f_1 + if_2 = z \mapsto \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$ is an isometry of $G$.

Q: Why introduce the metric $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}/y^2$ through these affine functions ($G,\circ)$?

It seems Do Carmo motivates the appearance of this metric as "the one left-invariant under composition of *real* affine Transformations" and then drops it and uses it on the complex upper half plane, which has a completely different structure to these affine transformations.

Through my approaches so far:

- I've had the Idea of looking at the equivalence relation $(f,g) \sim (\lambda f, \lambda g), \lambda \in \mathbb{C}^\times$. In this case: $(f_2t + f_1, g_2t + g_1) \sim (\frac{f_2t + f_1}{g_2t + g_1},1)$ which looks like a Möbius transformation, only $t \in \mathbb{R}$ in the Exercise. This didn't satisfy me but looks promising as $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is very close (acting on each component).
- If we add $z \mapsto -1/z$ we can then express the Möbius transformation as a composition of transformations of $G$. But then, why start with $G$ first?  (random guess, Does adding this inversion correspond to adding a point at infinity?)
- In euclidian spaces, such affine transformations are our "change of coordinates", which leave the metric invariant. Here, we show that the Möbius transormations in a more general setting when we add that inversion.
- These actions seem to give us a way to "straighten" two points to a "line".

Pointing in some direction for me to investigate would make me happy.

The context is a talk that I will give on closed geodesics in $\mathbb{H}/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and their relationship to class Numbers.

P.S. Having solved the Exercise, the discussion is not meant to be about a specific solution. Just the motivation behind the structure of the exercise.

Comment: Can you explain what $\delta_{ij}$ means to you? It pops up in the middle of your post with no explanation.

Comment: Similarly, can you explain what $f_1$ and $f_2$ represent?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is what Do Carmo is doing: 1) Show that the upper half plane has a Lie group structure by associating each point to a scalar affine function and defining group multiplication as composition of two affine functions. 2) Let $g$ be the left invariant metric such that at $(0,1)$, the metric is equal to the standard dot product on $\mathbb{R}^2$. 3) If you write $z = x + iy$, then Mobius transformations that preserve the half-plane are isometries of this left invariant metric. Are you asking why one would expect this metric to be the hyperbolic metric?

Comment: @LeeMosher The $\delta_{ij}$ was a shortcut way to write the Hyperbolic metric. For $u=(u^1,u^2),v= (v^1,v^2)$ in the Tangent Space at a point $p = (x,y) = yt+x$ of our Manifold, $\langle u, v \rangle_{(x,y)} = (1/y^2) \sum_i u^i v^i  = u^i u^j \delta_{ij} y^{-2}$. In my notation, $f_1$ and $f_2$ represent the components of the proper affine function in the sense that $(f_1,f_2) = f_2 t + f_1$, $f_2,f_1 \in \mathbb{R},f_2 > 0$.

Comment: @Deane It's more : The left invariant metric when the upper half plane is understood as the Lie Group of proper affine transformations (which coincides with the euclidian at $e$) is the Hyperbolic metric. 
Now, when looking at the upper half plane as the complex upper half plane, we use that metric again (hyperbolic space).
It seems Do Carmo motivates the appearance of this metric as "the one that is left-invariant under *real* affine Transformations" and then drops it and uses it on the complex upper half plane, which has a completely different structure to these affine transformations.

Comment: @Pastudent, I think that agrees with what I was saying. The group structure and Riemannian metric is obtained from the real affine functions (I think "transformation" is overstating it), but the complex structure arises only when you ask what the isometries of the metric is. It's not clear to me how you would anticipate the appearance of the complex structure from the group of affine functions.

Comment: @Deane Yes, I just wasn't sure whether that was what you meant. I see now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind this is a wonderful and weird coincidence that I cannot really explain, but which, as time passes, becomes more and more interesting to me (it has creeped into my most recent work-in-progress on the Dehn function of the group $\text{Aut}(F_n)$.) All I can suggest mathematically is that you work through the exercise.

But I suppose there are two ways that I look at this coincidence from an intuitive perspective, depending on whether you come at this first from the Riemannian geometry point of view, or first from the Lie group point of view.

And, by the way, I'll take the point of view that your Lie group is the semidirect product $\mathbb R \rtimes \mathbb R_>$, with respect to the homomorphism $\mathbb R_> \mapsto \text{Aut}(\mathbb R)$ that takes $t \in \mathbb R_>$ to the operation of multiplication by $t$ on $\mathbb R$.

One way goes like this (and this is how I first ran across this coincidence):

> Okay, here's the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H$. It's pretty remarkable. It has an interesting upper half plane model. It has constant negative curvature. Its group of orientation preserving isometries is the group $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$ acting by fractional linear transformations. That action is transitive and isotropic, although not free. Hmm... the isometry group of $\mathbb H$ has an interesting subgroup, namely the subgroup that fixes the point at infinity of the upper half plane. Hmm... that subgroup is a semidirect product $\mathbb R \rtimes \mathbb R_>$. OMG... that subgroup acts transitively and freely on $\mathbb H$... Wait, doesn't this sort of mean that $\mathbb H$ IS this Lie group, in some weird way?

The other way, which is my own souped up interpretation of what Do Carmo does, goes like this:

> Okay, here's this Lie group $\mathbb R \rtimes \mathbb R_>$. Like every Lie group, it has a left invariant metric that acts freely and transitively. So the Lie group itself is a subgroup of its own isometry group... hmm... I wonder what it's full group is isometries is ... OMG the full group of isometries not only acts transitively, it acts isotropically!! OMG the full group of isometries is the same as $\text{PSL}(2,\mathbb R)$ acting on $\mathbb H$! Wait... doesn't that sort of mean that this Lie group IS $\mathbb H$, in some weird sense?

---

One last comment: I actually stumbled across this coincidence in an even more backhanded way. There's a very cool theory of homogeneous Riemannian manifolds of negative curvature, relating them to certain Lie groups. I first learned about this in 3-dimensions: there's $\mathbb H^3$ but then there's a whole bunch of other ones that are not isotropic and that turn out to be solvable Lie groups of the form $\mathbb R^2 \rtimes \mathbb R_>$, using different actions of $\mathbb R_>$ on $\mathbb R^2$.

Only later did I realize that there's just one example in dimension 2, which is the topic of this whole post.

Comment: Geez. How is it possible that I never learned this before. Thanks!

Comment: There is an obvious way to generalize this Lie group to higher dimensions, namely positively oriented affine transformations of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Do these also arise in some natural geometric setting beyond just affine geometry?

Comment: I added a few comments about this. If you search on the phrase "homogeneous Riemannian manifolds of negative curvature" you'll run across more information.

Comment: I searched as you suggested and found a paper by Robert Azencott and Edward N. Wilson. I read only the beginning of the introduction, but it seems to say that any homogeneous Riemannian manifold with negative curvature is a LIe group with a left invariant metric. That sounds pretty amazing to me.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll have to digest it. Not sure It adds anything of value or whether/how it relates, but I want to put my current thinking out there. $C/\Lambda \sim C/\Lambda' \iff \Lambda' = \lambda \Lambda'$, for $\Lambda,\Lambda'$ Lattices. For $\omega_1,\omega_2$ basis of $\Lambda$, $A(\omega_1,\omega_2), A \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}$ gives the set of all possible bases. This means that $(\omega_1,\omega_2) \sim (\underbrace{\omega_1/\omega_2}_\tau,1)$. Looking at $A(\tau,1) = (a\tau + b, c\tau + d) \sim (\frac{a\tau +b}{c\tau +d},1)$. $a \tau +b$ looks "affine".

Comment: And you can identify $(\tau,1)$ with $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$ and do the same for $(\frac{a\tau + b}{ c\tau + d},1)$. In some sense, $\tau$ here is $e$ if we identify $\tau$ with $t$ and we obtain the Möbius Transformations. Visually, it looks like we related the affines to Möbius, but what happens with our left invariant metric (or how use it to connect the two in the steps $(a \tau + b, c\tau +d)$ and $(a \tau + b, c\tau +d) \sim \frac{a \tau + b}{c\tau +d}$ is unclear to me. (This is a refinement of my approach in the original post).

Comment: (I forgot a 1 somehwere and didn't discuss orientation so that the objects really lie in $\mathbb{H}$)

Comment: I don't think that lattices in $\mathbb C$, or elements of $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$, are really relevant here. The only thing going on here is that the metric you have denoted $\delta_{ij}$ is a left-invariant metric for the Lie group $G$, and --- lo and behold! --- it is also invariant under the fractional linear action of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ on $\mathbb H$. In order to make sense of this in a formal mathematical manner, for each $x, y \in \mathbb R$ you simply have to identify $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ with $x+iy \in \mathbb C$, which therefore lets you identify $G$ with $\mathbb H$.

Comment: If "identify" makes you uncomfortable, think of this as construction of a Riemannian isometry between $G$ and $\mathbb H$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I need some time to fully digest your points, but I do get the gist of it.  Being on a low level, my comment (replacing $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and forgetting Lattices) summarizes my attempt at constructing from the subgroup, its own group full group of isometries. (If $(t,1)$ is identified with $t$ (and $t = e$), we have through $(t,1) \sim \lambda (t,1), \lambda \in \mathbb{C}^\times$. Then $A(t,1) = (at+b,ct +d) \sim ((\frac{at+b}{ct + d},1)$, but I am unsure what happens with the metrics throughout these steps or how to land on my feet.)

Comment: Again, let me just emphasize: all this exercise is asking you to do is to prove that the metric $\delta_{ij}$ is unchanged when transformed by every element of the Lie group $G$, and that it is also invariant when transformed by every element of the group $SL_2(\mathbb R)$. So all you need to do is to write out how that metric is transformed in both of those cases, and check that the form of the metric is unchanged in both cases.

Comment: @LeeMosher I should have been clearer in the Post about the fact that I had already solved the exercise and that my question is only about that relationship.